# Referring to column name with alias

Tags: sql, presto

I wanted to know if when I alias tables, is it necessary to alias the columns when they are referred to in the statement, if they are unique to one table only?

For example:

```
where Salary > (select min(p.Salary) From Professors p inner join Departments d on p.Dept_id = d.Id where d.Dept_name = 'Art')

where Salary > (select min(Salary) From Professors p inner join Departments d on p.Dept_id = d.Id where Dept_name = 'Art')
```

If salary only exists in the professors table and Dept_name only exists in the Departments table, would either method above work? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't test for yourself *would either method above work*?

Comment: sorry didn't have access to an engine here without power so on phone and couldn't find documentation on this

Comment: Qualifying column references is a best practice but it is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column names are unique, you don't need to qualify them with a table name or alias. However, I believe it's good practice to qualify them.